# How to make Powershell DSC highly be Highly Available?

Tags: powershell, dsc, availability

Can PowerShell DSC be highly available?  What is the best practice?

Can i setup two pull servers and if one goes down the other one is automatically used?

Whats best practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use NLB (network load balancing) for the web part, not sure about the db, I don't think it can be highly available yet.